# Audio does not seem to output until I start changing the volume

Tags: audio

Whenever I boot up my machine, does not matter if Windows or Ubuntu (I have dual boot) the audio does not work, but then I press the buttons on my keyboard to decrease or decrease the volume and after tapping it 2 or 3 times, suddenly the audio starts working.

I should make clear that probably the keyboard has nothing to do about it most likely. I just said that changing the volume with the keyboard kinda brings audio "back to life", but also happens to me, that changing the volume of a YouTube video, just using the mouse and the software controls happened once. So I do not think that the keyboard has anything to do. I think that what triggers the audio back is the change of volume through software.

Sometimes I do not even need to change the volume. Just playing a video will automatically re-activate the volume after 1 or 2 seconds.

This clearly seems not to be an issue with the OS, because otherwise it wouldn't happen on both Linux and Windows. What could be the reason for this?

My motherboard is an ASUS P7H55-M PRO. [These are the specs](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P7H55M_PRO/specifications/).

Comment: What happens if you remove this keyboard and use a different one? Perhaps a keyboard without any audio controls of any sort.

Comment: I have updated the question with more details about it. Thanks for the remark.

Comment: Could it be that your audio device defaults to a sleeping mode?

Comment: How can I check that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Out-Of-Dated Sound Driver
Does Your Sound Card Support 'Realtek' ?
If So, Try Searching for an Update, you will find it Easily for it,

But if it's not a driver Issue, then you might try to run a BIOS test on your Sound Card in your BIOS Setup, see if it is a Keyboard Problem or Not, But i'm afraid it doesn't have anything to do with the keyboard.

Comment: Try Connecting "if you have one" a Bluetooth Headphone and see what will happen.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "Supporting Realtek", but I am running the latest firmware for my motherboard, which is where the Audio is integrated.